# How can I add customized CSS styles to django-ckeditor editor?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I wanna be able to add customized CSS styles that I've already defined on my CSS files. I read the documentation [here](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/152) and [here](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#optional-customizing-ckeditor-editor), but it just does not work.

**django-ckeditor version **

```
django-ckeditor       6.7.1
```

**This is ckeditor configs**

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'allowedContent': True,
        'stylesSet':[
            {
            'name':'highlighted-text', 'element':'div', 'attributes':{'class':'highlighted-text'}
            },
        ],
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [            
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['RemoveFormat', 'Source', 'Image', 'Table']
        ],
    }
}
```

**This is how django-ckeditor is looking like **

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would give a general answer. Which means, will cover all scenarios.
Not specific for `django-ckeditor`.

**Method : using custom css style file**

Methodology -

1)
Open desired webpage(page/area you want to customise) on chrome (any browser as you like)

2)
Right click area you want to style / customise

3)
Click on Open in `debug mode`(browser context menu)

4)
Find the `elements` you want to customise

5)
Copy `class` to a new text file

6)
Add your styles like below

```
.coped_class_name{
color:green !important;
}
```

7. 

Save this file with extension `.css`.
And
Move/copy this file to django static folder.

8)

Add this css file to your desired page.
And
Refresh the page.
Restart the server if styles does not show up.